# Java - Get all pixels inside of a circle on a Buffered Image

Tags: java, loops, bufferedimage, geometry

I wasn't able to find the solution to this problem online, sorry if this question is already asked before, also I think my question's title wasn't specific enough, so, I will explain in more details.

So, what I did is created a `BufferedImage` with a specific size and type, let's say for example:
`BufferedImage img1 = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);`
And what I am trying to do, is to use a "for" loop and loop thru every single image's pixel inside of an imaginary circle, lets say that circle starts on (X, Y)(0, 0), and ends on (X, Y)(500, 500).

Now, what I am trying to do, is to loop thru every single pixel inside of that imaginary circle, and then later, do something with that pixel (changing it's color for example).

Can anyone please help me do it? Thanks!

Comment: Afaik, You can cut this section inside that circle out, putting it into a path, convert it to a pixel array, and then loop over it. Did something with Win32Api 9 years ago, may be, the related objects have similar names.

Comment: Sure, sounds like a good idea, do you maybe have any example codes that show how I could do that?

Comment: Would need to research by myself... Maybe googling for java, 2d, drawing, canvas, get intersection or section will help

Comment: A) stackoverflow is not a code-writing service, you’re expected to do some research first and explain where you are stuck B) a circle doesn’t have a beginning and an end, your definition if your circle is incomplete and ambiguous. Are you defining the bounding box or does your circle lie on these two points ? Normally you define a circle by its midpoint and radius although bounding box is common too.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/primitives.html

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an idea that could solve this problem not only for circles, but also for any other shapes.

So, my idea is to create another Buffered Image, make it the same size as the one i want to edit (work on), make sure that all of it's pixels are blank (transparent), and draw a shape that you want on that new image (a circle for example) also, we keep the track of the shape's color, and the shape needs to be filled.

After that, we loop thru each pixel on the image that we want to edit using the for loops and the x, y integer variables, each time the loop repeats, we check on the shape's image to see if the shape is drawn there, and to do that we check if the pixel color is same as the shape's color on the shape's image. And if it is, the loop has detected the coordinates to the pixel inside of the shape, and then we can do something with it. (The for loops use the X and Y coordinate integers)

Here is an example code:

```
public static BufferedImage yourMethodName(BufferedImage inputImage, Point circlePosition, Dimension circleSize)
{
    BufferedImage outputImage = inputImage;
    BufferedImage circleImage = new BufferedImage(inputImage.getWidth(), inputImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics drawOnCircleImg = circleImage.getGraphics();
    Color circleColor = new Color(0, 255, 0);

    drawOnCircleImg.setColor(circleColor);
    drawOnCircleImg.fillOval(circlePosition.x, circlePosition.y, circleSize.width, circleSize.height);

    for(int y = 0; y < outputImage.getHeight(); y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < outputImage.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            if(circleImage.getRGB(x, y) == circleColor.getRGB())
            {
                //PIXEL IS INSIDE OF THE SHAPE, IT IS DETECTED, DO SOMETHING NOW
                //VARIABLES FOR THE PIXEL POSITION ARE: X, Y
            }
        }
    }

    return outputImage;
}
```